# Punctuation in "wrappers in this language"

Tags: punctuation, reduced-relative-clauses

I wrote:

> We offer an algorithm to apply **wrappers in this language** to web pages.

I guess the bold part is a reduced relative clause, right? if not what is it?

> We offer an algorithm to apply wrappers [that are] in this language to web pages

What is the required punctuation for that part, do I need comma? 
Moreover, do I need "the" before "wrappers"?

Comment: Might be better to use "*name-of-your-language* wrappers to web pages", e.g. "javascript wrappers", "php wrappers", "html wrappers", or do you mean "containers"?

Comment: @Peter you can replace "wrapper" with "program", it's the name of specific programs which extract data from web pages.